# Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable how fix this?

Tags: php, header, countable

I have an error this : Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

```
public static function setSection( $section, $section_data = array(), $additional_section_data = array() ) {
    if(count($additional_section_data) > 0 && !empty($additional_section_data)){
        $section_data['fields'] = array_merge($section_data['fields'], $additional_section_data);
    }

    self::$sections[ $section ] = $section_data;
}
```

Comment: var_dump() both `$section_data['fields']` and `$additional_section_data` and see what you get.

Comment: `$additional_section_data` is probably not an array when you call this function. It will be an array if you omit the parameter but when you don't omit the parameter you need to ensure you pass a countable.

Answer (score -1):

This issue means the variable `$section_data` isn't an array. Try to use `gettype` function to find out the type of the var, or `var_dump` to display it.

Comment: If you remove this you'll get an issue on the next line in the function array_merge. $additional_section_data isn't an array, an isn't empty. What you'll get in the result array?)